# Find the general solution of $\sin^2 x = \sin^2 \theta$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the general solution of $\sin^2 x = \sin^2 \theta$.

My Attempt:
$$\sin^2 x = \sin^2 \theta$$
$$\sin^2 x - \sin^2 \theta=0$$
$$(\sin x + \sin \theta) (\sin x - \sin \theta)=0$$
$$(2\sin \dfrac {x+\theta}{2}.\cos \dfrac {x-\theta}{2}).(2\sin \dfrac {x-\theta}{2}.\cos \dfrac {x+\theta }{2})=0$$.

...

Comment: 1. What is $y$? (I think you have a typo). 2. Do you know what makes a product $0$?

Comment: Stop here: $(\sin x + \sin \theta) (\sin x - \sin \theta)=0$. Now, $ (\sin x + \sin \theta) = 0$ or $(\sin x - \sin \theta)=0$

Answer (score 2):

In your last step you are almost there. You have

$$ (2\sin \dfrac {x+\theta}{2}.\cos \dfrac {x-\theta}{2}).(2\sin \dfrac {x-\theta}{2}.\cos \dfrac {x+\theta }{2})=0 $$

This gives

$$\sin(x+\theta)\sin(x-\theta)=0$$

So either

$$ \sin(x+\theta)=0\text{ or }\sin(x-\theta)=0 $$

Thus

$$ \text{Either } x=n\pi-\theta\text{ or }x=n\pi+\theta$$

Giving the solution

$$x=n\pi\pm\theta$$

As others have pointed out, you could have gotten there sooner from your third step.